# Chrome favicon.ico GET request

Tags: php, apache, google-chrome, http, browser

Given the following script:

```
<?php
syslog(LOG_INFO,'$_GET: '.print_r($_GET,1));
var_dump($_GET);
?>
```

Using http://www.example.com/testing/chrome.php?x=123 as the URI produces the expected results:

```
array(1) { ["x"]=> string(3) "123" }
```

But when viewing the system log and Apache access log, I have another GET variable named "cid" whose value is "favicon.ico" when using the Chrome browser Version 39.0.2171.71 m (but not FF or IE).

What causes this, and is there a way to prevent my server from being hit twice for each request?

System Log

```
Dec  7 07:33:09 devserver test: $_GET: Array#012(#012    [x] => 123#012)
Dec  7 07:33:09 devserver test: $_GET: Array#012(#012    [cid] => favicon.ico#012)
```

Apache Log

```
192.168.1.1 - Michael [07/Dec/2014:07:33:09 -0800] "GET /testing/chrome.php?x=123 HTTP/1.1" 200 36 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36"
192.168.1.1 - Michael [07/Dec/2014:07:33:09 -0800] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 46 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What causes this, and is there a way to prevent my server from being hit twice for each request?

Chrome and other browsers will look for your site's favicon in `/favicon.ico`. Put an empty file there rather than having your script handle that URL and you should be all set.

Comment: To compound the odd behavior, I had a redirect rule which made pretty URLs of `index.php?cid=xxx` when accessing example.com/xxx and /xxx is not a file or directory.  Adding an empty file solved the problem.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Best way to avoid this is by adding a empty favicon

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="#" />`

Comment: Some browsers will fallback to `/favicon.ico` when it can't get the one from the `<link>` tag, IIRC.